# Access multiple files using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using HTML 5 Multiple files ability to select multiple files for upload. The files come as an array of files in the `$_FILES` variable. I want to use jQuery to get all the names of the files listed before upload button is clicked.

```
<input class="pictures-upload" name="multiplePhotos[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

I want to append a onchange event that when a person clicks the upload files and selects multiple files, it will take names of all files and append it on the body of html. I am using

```
$('.upload_button').live('change', function () {
     var li = $('<li />').text($(this).val()),
     $('#body').append(li);

 });
```

This takes only the last file to be selected. How do I get all the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input element has a native property of 'files' which is a [FileList](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist) type (i.e. a sequence of [File](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file)). If you have a look at the W3 spec for the [File](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file) element, you'll discover what properties you can access.

However, long story short, the jQuery [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method won't return what you want. Since 'files' is a native property of the input element, you can access it directly using `this.files`. Then just iterate over the array to get the File objects that you can get get the information for (name, size, type, etc).

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var file = this.files[i];
    $fileList.append('<li>' + file.name + '</li>');
}
```

Look here for the jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/bdbXk/

Comment: I have checked the File API but could not figure out if there a way of manipulating the filelist e.g if I want to delete on item from it? I have tried to look around but do not see anything.